# Disable Digital Wellbeing using Android Management API in Kiosk mode

Tags: android-management-api

We are using Android Management API in an enterprise environment where we have multiple devices enrolled as *dedicated devices* in kiosk mode running a custom private app.

Sometimes when the user activates the device there will be a popup from `Digital Wellbeing` with the message "**Need time to focus?** Use Focus mode to pause distracting apps."

We are using the following policy:

```
"applications": [
    {
    "packageName": "PRIVATE_ENTERPRISE_APP",
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
    "installType": "KIOSK",
    "autoUpdateMode": "AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY"
    }
],
"statusReportingSettings": {
    "applicationReportsEnabled": false,
    "deviceSettingsEnabled": true,
    "softwareInfoEnabled": true,
    "memoryInfoEnabled": true,
    "networkInfoEnabled": true,
    "displayInfoEnabled": true,
    "powerManagementEventsEnabled": true,
    "hardwareStatusEnabled": true,
    "systemPropertiesEnabled": true
},
"screenCaptureDisabled": true,
"adjustVolumeDisabled": true,
"keyguardDisabled": true,
"autoDateAndTimeZone": "AUTO_DATE_AND_TIME_ZONE_ENFORCED",
"kioskCustomization": {
    "deviceSettings": "SETTINGS_ACCESS_ALLOWED",
    "statusBar": "NOTIFICATIONS_AND_SYSTEM_INFO_DISABLED"
},
"openNetworkConfiguration": {
    "NetworkConfigurations": [{
    "GUID": "WIFINETWORK",
    "Name": "WIFINETWORK",
    "Type": "WiFi",
    "WiFi": {
        "SSID": "WIFINETWORK",
        "Security": "WPA-PSK",
        "Passphrase": "WIFIPASSWORD",
        "AutoConnect": true,
        "MACAddressRandomizationMode": "Hardware"
    }
    }]
}
```

Because we are running one custom app in kiosk mode and explicitly disable the keyguard, notifications and system information, the lockscreen should not be hijacked by a system app that has no relevance to the kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **uninstall** or **block** the default system app ***Digital Wellbeing*** by using `"installType": "BLOCKED"`, the app is blocked and can’t be installed. If the app was installed under a previous policy, it will be uninstalled.

The alternative to blocking the app completely is to just [deny](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#permissiongrant) the notification permission for the app.

**Sample code** (Note that the package name of the wellbeing app varies depending on the manufacturer - e.g. for Samsung devices the package name would be **com.samsung.android.wellbeing**):

```
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.google.samples.apps.iosched",
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
    "installType": "KIOSK"
  },
  {
    "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.wellbeing",
    "installType": "BLOCKED",
    "permissionGrants": [
      {
        "permission": "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS",
        "policy": "DENY"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```